# div hidden after socket connection

Tags: javascript, html, sockets

i'm trying to manipulate some divs. I want a div to disappear just after socket connection.For exemple i want to div1 to be hidden just when the socket is connected. how could i do that.  here is the code :

```
!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var socket = io.connect("127.0.0.1:8080");
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<img id="drag1" src="img_logo.gif" draggable="true"
ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you try io.on('connection', function (){$("div1").hide()});

Comment: but you have to emit it to backend side\

Comment: what do you mean by emit it to backend side ?

Comment: read this docs http://socket.io/docs/

Answer (score 0):

You simply can use a emitter (`emit`) on your **server-side** script and a listener on your **client-side**. For example:

On your **server-side** script you need to put under this line, something similar like `socket.on("connection", function(...`

This line:

```
socket.emit("isConnected", { isConnected: true });
```

Now on your **client-side** you need to listen to the emitter like this:

```
socket.on("isConnected", function(data) {
    // Receive the 'data' and check if 'isConnected' is true

    if(data.isConnected == true) {
        // Now hide the div.
        getElementById("div1").style.display:"none";
    }
});
```

Comment: it worked with : getelementByid("div1").style.display:"none";

Comment: So it worked 100% for you? I have updated my anser with your code.